# Using CUDA Thrust to evaluate recurrence relations for nonlinear partial differential equations

Tags: algorithm, cuda, thrust, differential-equations

I need to compute double precision recurrence relations of the form

1. X[n] = A[n]*X[n-1] + B[n]
2. X[n] = A[n]*X[n-1] + B[n]*X[n-2] + C[n]

I'm using these in conjunction with nonlinear PDE's. Is Thrust's inclusive scan operator flexible enough to compute these?

Comment: A recurrence relation isn't mathematically the same thing as a (segmented) prefix sum so whether thrust's scan algorithm could or couldn't be coerced to do what you have written is likely to be irrelevant.

Comment: 1. seems possible; 2. I'm not sure of due to the `X[n-2]` term.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by talonmies, recurrence relations involved in the solution of nonlinear partial differential equations are something different from prefix sums.

The above relations are typically in the form of *update* relations like

[image]

see also the book "Partial Difference Equations" by Sui Sun Cheng.

To evaluate this *update* equation in parallel, a possibility is using zip iterators in conjunction with transforms, as in the below example

```
#include <thrust\device_vector.h>

struct Recurrence{
template <typename Tuple>
    __host__ __device__ double operator()(Tuple a) {

        // --- X[n] = A[n]*X[n-1] + B[n]*X[n-2] + C[n]
        return (thrust::get<0>(a) * thrust::get<3>(a) + thrust::get<1>(a) * thrust::get<4>(a) + thrust::get<2>(a));

    }
};


int main() {

    const int N = 10;

    thrust::device_vector<double> d_x(N, 1.f);
    thrust::device_vector<double> d_a(N, 2.f);
    thrust::device_vector<double> d_b(N, 3.f);
    thrust::device_vector<double> d_c(N, 4.f);

    thrust::transform(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_a.begin() + 2, d_b.begin() + 2, d_c.begin() + 2, d_x.begin() + 1,     d_x.begin())), 
                      thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_a.begin() + N, d_b.begin() + N, d_c.begin() + N, d_x.begin() + N - 1, d_x.begin() + N - 2)), 
                      d_x.begin() + 2, Recurrence());

    for (int i=2; i<N; i++) {
        double temp = d_x[i];
        printf("%i %f\n", i, temp);
    }

    return 0;
}
```